# Implementing trait with method returning generic trait

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I am trying to design a pair of traits (e.g. `RowVector` and `ColumnVector` from linear algebra) where each trait returns the other from one of its methods (e.g. `transpose`). I want to be able to add implementations of either trait in the future (such as dense and sparse vector implementations).

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate derive_new;

trait RowVector<Element> {
    fn transpose(self) -> ColumnVector<Element>;
}

trait ColumnVector<Element> {
    fn transpose(self) -> RowVector<Element>;
}

#[derive(new, Debug)]
struct VecRowVector<Element> {
    vec: Vec<Element>
}

#[derive(new, Debug)]
struct VecColumnVector<Element> {
    vec: Vec<Element>
}

impl<Element> RowVector<Element> for VecRowVector<Element> {
    fn transpose(self) -> VecColumnVector<Element> {
        VecColumnVector::new(self.vec)
    }
}

impl<Element> ColumnVector<Element> for VecColumnVector<Element> {
    fn transpose(self) -> VecRowVector<Element> {
        VecRowVector::new(self.vec)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let row_vector = VecRowVector::new(vec![1,2,3]);
    let col_vector = VecColumnVector::new(vec![1,2,3]);
    println!("{:?}", row_vector.transpose());
    println!("{:?}", col_vector.transpose());
}
```

I get an error saying that `VecColumnVector` is not a `ColumnVector` and it's expecting a `'static` value.

```
error[E0053]: method `transpose` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> src\main.rs:22:31
   |
4  |         fn transpose(self) -> ColumnVector<Element>;
   |                               --------------------- type in trait
...
22 |         fn transpose(self) -> VecColumnVector<Element> {
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait ColumnVector, found struct `VecColumnVector`
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(VecRowVector<Element>) -> ColumnVector<Element> + 'static`
   = note:    found type `fn(VecRowVector<Element>) -> VecColumnVector<Element>`
```

Have I not made `VecColumnVector` a subtype of `ColumnVector`? Or do I somehow need to tell the trait that it doesn't need to be a `static` lifetime?

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to return a trait. While this is possible using a [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html), it probably isn't what you want to do. A better design would be to introduce a `Transpose` trait, which you can model in a similar way to Rust's built-in `From` and `Into` conversion traits.

```
trait Transpose<To> {
    fn transpose(self) -> To;
}

impl<Element> Transpose<VecColumnVector<Element>> for VecRowVector<Element> {
    fn transpose(self) -> VecColumnVector<Element> {
        VecColumnVector::new(self.vec)
    }
}

impl<Element> Transpose<VecRowVector<Element>> for VecColumnVector<Element> {
    fn transpose(self) -> VecRowVector<Element> {
        VecRowVector::new(self.vec)
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I update the `RowVector` and `ColumnVector` traits to indicate that every struct that implements them must also implement the corresponding `Transpose`?

Comment: I think that will get quite complicated: there will be cyclic references between constraints on each of the traits, because you will have to define the impls in strict pairs, which is hard to express in Rust. A much simpler (and more flexible) design is to not enforce any constraints on the types themselves, but rather to put constraints on the places where the types are used.

Comment: So I couldn't write functions like `f<Element>(r: &RowVector<Element>, c: &ColumnVector<Element>)` and expect to be able use `transpose` in the body? I have to list `Transpose` along with the other linear algebra operations that I will need?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way, but I can't directly see it, and it will probably take a bit of restructuring first. It _feels_ like you are trying to shoehorn a Java-like paradigm - using traits in place of interfaces - and this doesn't really fit with how people program in Rust.

Answer (score 2):

When two types need to be related, the best solution is often [associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/associated-types.html). This precludes using dynamic dispatch like a trait object, but dynamic dispatch is still pretty limited in Rust. Rust is more expressive with static dispatch, which associated types leverage.

```
pub trait RowVector<Element>: Sized {
    type Transpose: ColumnVector<Element>;

    fn transpose(self) -> Self::Transpose;
}

pub trait ColumnVector<Element>: Sized {
    type Transpose: RowVector<Element>;

    fn transpose(self) -> Self::Transpose;
}

pub struct VecRowVector<Element> {
    pub vec: Vec<Element>
}

pub struct VecColumnVector<Element> {
    pub vec: Vec<Element>
}

impl<Element> RowVector<Element> for VecRowVector<Element> {
    type Transpose = VecColumnVector<Element>;

    fn transpose(self) -> VecColumnVector<Element> {
        VecColumnVector { vec: self.vec }
    }
}

impl<E: Debug> ColumnVector<Element> for VecColumnVector<Element> {
    type Transpose = VecRowVector<Element>;

    fn transpose(self) -> VecRowVector<Element> {
        VecRowVector { vec: self.vec }
    }
}
```